# PayPal: перевод с аккаунта на аккаунт или карту

Tags: yii2, paypal, paypal-api

Суть задачи: мне надо что бы пользователи через мой сайт могли перевести деньги другому пользователю на аккаунт PayPal или на карту. Данные карты или аккаунта я буду знать заранее (куда переводить).

То есть, мне надо что бы пользователь указал данные своей карты или аккаунта PayPal и сделал перевод.

Можно что бы это делалось на стороне PayPal, главное что бы пользователь мог указать сумму и сайт получал уведомление, если все прошло хорошо.

Сайт сайт делаю на Yii2

Comment: A PayPal component for Yii framework to utilize Express Checkout and Direct Payment APIs https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/paypal |||  PayPal payment extension fpr the Yii2 https://github.com/marciocamello/yii2-paypal  ||| PayPal extension for the Yii2 https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/davidjeddy/yii2-paypal

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но мне бы название метода. я не смог найти его

Comment: Встроенного метода нет - придется ставить полностью решение - упростить не получится - предлагаемое оптимизировано, далее просто работать не будет. Хотя, кто знает - подождите, может, кто что и скажет.